# Array In New Activity String

Tags: android

So far I have an `Array` which is populated by a `EditText` box. I am trying to pass this `Array` to a new `Activity` and then populate a `String` in the new `Activity` with the values of the `Array` from the previous `Activity`

So far I have this:

`ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();`

And my Button:

```
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playnow);
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent( demo.AddRemove.this, demo.PasswActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable( "com.example.playerList", playerList );
i.putExtras( extras );
startActivity( i );

}});
```

So I need to some how get the valus of that `Array` to populate this `String` like this `{ "name1", "name2", "name3" }` which is in a new Activty:

`initWheel(R.id.passw_1, new String[] {  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use [`extras.putStringArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)  instead of `extras.putSerializable`.
You can get back the value using [`getStringArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getStringArrayList%28java.lang.String%29)

Use [ArrayList.toArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) function to convert ArrayList to array object

Comment: can you expand a bit futhur? Ive added this in my new `Activity` `Intent intent = getIntent();
  String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("com.example.playerList");`

Comment: use getStringArrayList instead of getStringArrayExtra

Comment: I just get the error `The method getStringArrayList(String) is undefined for the type Intent` with that argument though?

Comment: not for intent. you will have to do intent.getextras().getStringArrayList

Comment: Ahh ok so it would have to be `intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("com.example.playerList");`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6654/discussion-between-matt-and-nandeesh)

Answer (score 0):

In the receiving activity, you can use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
extras.get......
```

In your case, what I would do is put the string variables in an Array instead of the EditText objects. In the receiving activity you directly have access to the String array that you want.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I've got the `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` after my onCreate

Comment: Could you post that code, what you exactly give as input and what you exactly want as output? What is not working?

Comment: Shall we join a chat may be easier?